# What is the best way to work cross-platform with an IDE/editor for Python indentation?

Tags: python, ide, indentation

I have python code that I have to run on multiple servers (1 Windows and 2 Linux). I always get indentation error.

I tried multiple methods and always get an issue. I tried to use TAB as indent and also used 4 SPACES, but always get either error or the script does not run in a way it should

I cannot show the whole code but here is part of it:

```
Sec_all = 0
sk = 0
my = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
  for i in df_Filter["iMap"]:
    #i = 65   #comment
    sk = sk + 1
    print("SK i = " + str(i) + "  @ " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
    y = z[:, (i)]#,54,133,122,63,102,105,39]
    X = df.drop(Code, axis=1, errors='ignore')
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=42)
    
   
  
  print("********** : " + str(99999))
  for i in df_my[df_my["Sec_x"].isnull()]["iMap_x"]:
    print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : " + str(i))
    my = my + 1
    print("My i = " + str(i) + "  @ " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
    y = z[:, (i)]#,54,133,122,63,102,105,39]
    X = df.drop(Code, axis=1, errors='ignore')
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=42)

  print(">>>>>>>>>>> F1_mi score All : ", F1_mi)
  print(">>>>>>>>>>> F1_ma score All : ", F1_ma)
```

I google to find if I can use brackets or any other clear way to determine FOR blocks (begin and end) but clearly python does not support that.

is there any other method i can be sure that indentation will be compiled as intended?

Comment: Get a proper IDE - PyCharm.  Make sure you replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Your example code clearly uses 2 spaces, not 4.  This part doesn't in itself have any obvious indentation errors, but if you're using 2 spaces in some parts of your code and 4 in others, that could easily cause problems.  The most important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: You apparently regularly ask questions on Stack Overflow, have multiple gold badges and an account nearing 10 years old; so I shouldn't have to tell you that subjective questions about coding style [are off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here, and so are complaints about how Python does things. The indentation in the code you show appears fine; but clearly it uses 2 spaces for indent, not 4 (and not a tab). You can get errors for other reasons, such as just not putting things at the correct level of indentation even though you type the indentation consistently.

Comment: I work cross platform between Windows and Linux frequently using the Spyder IDE.  I also believe PyCharm will also work but don't use very much.

Comment: That said, no, you may not mix tabs and spaces in your indentation. We can't teach you how to be consistent; we can only point you at the [Python community recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (In the future, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look things up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+indentation+best+practice) yourself.) If the source code has indentation problems and it's not because of what you typed yourself, that's a problem with your IDE.

Comment: Check out the [Black formatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which indents and auto-formats your python code to best practice style goodness.

Comment: Your original title was too vague, were you looking for advice on a) whether to use tabs in Python source (don't! especially multiplatform) b) recommendations for cross-platform editor/IDEs? c) recommendations for specific settings about whitespace in a specific editor/IDE? So I edited the title to *"What is the best way to work cross-platform with an IDE/editor for Python indentation?"*, feel free to edit it to something closer to what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

The issue is that empty lines in between code lines cause indent issues in Linux server.

I removed all empty lines and the code seems to run smoothly.